# Gradient-descent algorithm always converges to the closest local optima?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Assume $f(\vec x)$, which is Lipschitz continuous, has two local optima $\vec x_1^*$ and $\vec x_2^*$( $\vec x_1^*$ is the global minimum). We start the gradient-descent algorithm from $\vec x_0$ and $\left \|\vec x_0 - \vec x_1^* \right \| \leq \left \|\vec x_0 - \vec x_2^* \right \|$. Additionally, we know between $\vec x_0$ and $\vec x_1^*$, $f(\vec x)$ is convex, but between $x_1^*$ and $x_2^*$, $f(\vec x)$ is not convex.

Can we say initialized at $\vec x_0$ using gradient-descent algorithm and it always converge to $\vec x_1^*$ rather than $\vec x_2^*$? Is there any THM to support this? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You have tagged this as convex-optimization, which I suspect affects the answer. Your question doesn't mention whether or not the function must be convex though.

Comment: @DavisYoshida I have modified my question:)

Comment: It depends on the choice of step size. If the step size is very large you might end up at $\vec x^*_2$ on the first step.

Comment: @Rahul Make sense. Thanks:)

Comment: Seeing as you've started a bounty, can you elaborate on what you're looking for?

Comment: @Rahul is there any THM to support your previous comment?

Comment: Perhaps if you define precisely what you mean by "between $\vec x_0$ and $\vec x_1^*$, $f(\vec x)$ is convex".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no guarantee that you will converge to $x_1$. This also depends on the choice of your step size. Let us recall that the [gradient descent algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) is defined by
$$ \vec x^{k+1} = \vec x^k -\gamma_k \nabla f(\vec x^k)$$
where $\gamma_k$ is the step size. First let us show that if you choose a constant step size then you can always find a counter example. So suppose $\gamma_k = \gamma$ for every $k$.
Now consider the function 
$$f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \frac{2}{\gamma}x^2 & \text{if }x \leq 1\\  \frac{2}{\gamma} &\text{else } \end{array}\right. \quad \text{ then }\quad f'(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \frac{4}{\gamma}x & \text{if }x \leq 1 \\ 0 &\text{else } \end{array}\right.$$
and the points $x_0=-\frac{2}{3} ,x_1=0, x_2 = 2$ (so that $|x_0-x_1| < |x_0-x_2|$). In particular the first step of the Gradient descent would be
$$ x_0-\gamma f'(x_0) = -\frac{2}{3} + \frac{4}{\gamma}\gamma \frac{2}{3} = 2 = x_2. $$
And it will get stuck on $x_2$ since $f'(x_2)=0$ so the next step would be
$x_2 -\gamma f'(x_2) = x_2$, and so on. In the picture below you can find the plot of $f$ for $\gamma = 2$.

[image: example of $f$ with $\gamma = 2$]
Now one could argue that the choice of a constant step size is a bad choice and setting
$$\gamma_k = \arg\min_{\gamma \geq 0} f(\vec x^k-\gamma \nabla f(\vec x^k)),\qquad (*)$$
would be better (i.e. we choose the step to optimize the descent). However this is not always true! It is shown in the lecture notes of *Convex Optimization* of M. Hein that the function
$$ f(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 5\sqrt{9x^2+16y^2} & \text{if }x >|y| \\ 9x+16|y| &\text{else } \end{array}\right.$$
is pathological enough so that if you start the Gradient Descent algorithm with steepest descent (i.e. $\gamma^k$ fulfills $(*)$ at each step) with $(1,\left(\frac{10}{16}\right)^2)$ then the method will converge to $(0,0)$ which is not even a local minima. While the choice of a constant step size $\gamma $ small enough will (slowly) tend to $(-\infty, 0)$.

**Note:** Very complete informations about the Gradient Descent algorithm (and its "applications limit") can be found in the book [Convex Optimization](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) by S. Boyd and L. Vandenberghe.

Comment: So your suggestion is to set the step size small. But even though there still is no theoretically guarantee of converging to x1, right?

Comment: Hi @Surb, could you please have a look at my related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564427/is-the-sequence-x-n-in-gradient-descent-algorithm-convergent)?

Answer (score 5):

The distance between pairs of points doesn't have anything to do locally with the directional derivative of the function as it varies in between trajectories from $x_0$ to the two points $x_1,x_2$. You could have $||x_0 - x_1|| < ||x_0 - x_2||$ and yet the local gradient at $x_0$ says to go toward point $x_2$ instead of $x_1$. And convexity/lack of convexity in the middle range between $x_0$ and $x_1,x_2$ has nothing to do with it either, because gradient descent is a local method that just relies on gradients and not second derivatives. You could very well converge to $x_2$ with gradient descent. Maybe not with more sophisticated methods.

Comment: but if I use gradient descent from $x_0$ with very small step size, because the convexity between $x_0$ and $x_1$, $f(x)$ must converge to $x_1$, right?

Comment: @user137273 No, I don't believe that's true. The directional derivative could locally be greater headed toward point $x_2$ instead of $x_1$, even though the function fails to be always convex in between $x_0$ and $x_2$.

Comment: @2566092 what if $x_1$ is the global optima? In your opinion, if and only if the directional derivative toward $x_1$ is greater than $x_2$, my claim is correct, right?